# Sql Between Clause for multiple columns

Tags: sql

I try to implement a query by using Between Clause,but there is some problem in this

first query for S_E1:

this query return exact data which i require and here data count is 43.

```
select RECORD_TIMESTAMP as DateRecorded, ROUND (S_E1 ,2 )as S_E1
from TBL_SENSORS
Where RECORD_TIMESTAMP Between '4/28/2012 12 :00 AM' 
                           and '5/17/2012 12 :00 AM'
And ( S_E1 Between 10 And 100 )
```

Second Query for S_E2:

this query return exact data which i require and here data count is 68.

```
select RECORD_TIMESTAMP as DateRecorded, ROUND (S_E2 ,2 )as S_E2
from TBL_SENSORS
Where RECORD_TIMESTAMP Between '4/28/2012 12 :00 AM'
                           and '5/17/2012 12 :00 AM'
And ( S_E2 Between 10 And 100 )
```

**Problem :**

But when i combine these to queries in a single query then it give wrong data.It gives me 73 rows.I think it should give 111 rows

```
select RECORD_TIMESTAMP as DateRecorded, 
       ROUND (S_E2 ,2 )as S_E2, 
       ROUND (S_E1 ,2 ) as S_E1
from TBL_SENSORS
Where RECORD_TIMESTAMP Between '4/28/2012 12 :00 AM'
                           and '5/17/2012 12 :00 AM'
And ( S_E2 Between 10 And 100) 
and (S_E1 Between 10 And 100  )
```

Please give some idea where i am wrong here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OR` instead of `AND` opeartor

```
SELECT RECORD_TIMESTAMP AS DateRecorded, 
       Round (S_E2, 2)  AS S_E2, 
       Round (S_E1, 2)  AS S_E1 
FROM   TBL_SENSORS 
WHERE  RECORD_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN '4/28/2012 12 :00 AM' AND '5/17/2012 12 :00 AM' 
       or ( S_E2 BETWEEN 10 AND 100 ) 
       or ( S_E1 BETWEEN 10 AND 100 )
```

In the query, it is not guaranteed that you will get 111 records because there may be common records for two conditions.

condition 1 - `( S_E2 BETWEEN 10 AND 100 )`

condition 2  - `( S_E1 BETWEEN 10 AND 100 )`

Or

Use Union All in two queries to get all records (111).

```
select RECORD_TIMESTAMP as DateRecorded, ROUND (S_E1 ,2 )as S_E1, 0 as S_E2
from TBL_SENSORS
Where RECORD_TIMESTAMP Between '4/28/2012 12 :00 AM' and '5/17/2012 12 :00 AM'
And ( S_E1 Between 10 And 100 )

UNION ALL

select RECORD_TIMESTAMP as DateRecorded, 0 as S_E1, ROUND (S_E2 ,2 ) as S_E2
from TBL_SENSORS
Where RECORD_TIMESTAMP Between '4/28/2012 12 :00 AM'
and '5/17/2012 12 :00 AM'
And ( S_E2 Between 10 And 100 )
```

Comment: He's not using UNION anywhere.

Comment: @Romil thanks for reply.You are right i am working with OR now.But problem is that now SE_1 or S_E2 also show -ve values.There count is 73.Data is so precious here because it deal with real time Sensors.Do you have any solution or idea for this.

Comment: see the second solution, it will return all records.

Comment: Yes you are right but here i have 161 columns and user have to select it from checkbox list.What i can do in this case.

Comment: Please share a query with three or more columns, so I can more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should make a union between the two statements or you should use the "OR" instead of the AND.

```
select RECORD_TIMESTAMP as DateRecorded,ROUND (S_E2 ,2 )as S_E2,ROUND (S_E1 ,2 )as S_E1 from TBL_SENSORS Where RECORD_TIMESTAMP Between '4/28/2012 12 :00 AM' and '5/17/2012 12 :00 AM' AND (( S_E2 Between 10 And 100) OR(S_E1 Between 10 And 100 ))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the restrictions of S_E2 and S_E1.

In order to them to work like intended you have to use `UNION ALL`:

```
select RECORD_TIMESTAMP as DateRecorded, ROUND (S_E1 ,2 )as S_E
from TBL_SENSORS
Where RECORD_TIMESTAMP Between '4/28/2012 12 :00 AM' and '5/17/2012 12 :00 AM'
And ( S_E1 Between 10 And 100 )

UNION ALL

select RECORD_TIMESTAMP as DateRecorded, ROUND (S_E2 ,2 )as S_E
from TBL_SENSORS
Where RECORD_TIMESTAMP Between '4/28/2012 12 :00 AM'
and '5/17/2012 12 :00 AM'
And ( S_E2 Between 10 And 100 )
```

---

or you use an `OR` instead of an `AND` like this:

```
select RECORD_TIMESTAMP as DateRecorded, 
       ROUND (S_E2 ,2 )as S_E2, 
       ROUND (S_E1 ,2 ) as S_E1
from TBL_SENSORS
Where RECORD_TIMESTAMP Between '4/28/2012 12 :00 AM'
                           and '5/17/2012 12 :00 AM'
And ( (S_E2 Between 10 And 100) OR (S_E1 Between 10 And 100)  )
```

Since the only difference in the restrictions are from S_E1 and S_E2 columns, if you use `AND` you are saying that all records have to respect both restrictions. In the separated queries they only respect one so you have to make it that way in the main query.

Answer (score 1):

Change the boolean logic, by placing extra parenthesis and replace the last AND to OR

```
select RECORD_TIMESTAMP as DateRecorded, 
       ROUND (S_E2 ,2 )as S_E2, 
       ROUND (S_E1 ,2 ) as S_E1
from TBL_SENSORS
Where RECORD_TIMESTAMP Between '4/28/2012 12 :00 AM'
                           and '5/17/2012 12 :00 AM'
And (( S_E2 Between 10 And 100) 
OR (S_E1 Between 10 And 100  ))
```